# Valor de variable en arguments[0] a variable de session

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito asignar una variable de SESSION de php, con el valor arguments[0] de una funcion de js.
Se puede hacer?

```
"PHP"................"JS"

$_SESSION['id_ad'] =  arguments[0];
```

Comment: ¿Cómo comunicas entre el cliente y el servidor?  ¿Envías más cosas desde Javascript? Comenta un poco más sobre lo que hace el programa, quizá se te puedan sugerir mejores técnicas.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad te faltan datos pero intentare ayudarte, por ejemplo podrías enviarlos mediante un archivo javascript al php haciendo uso una variable de tipo GET por ejemplo:
En el archivo html o en el javascript:

```
<script>location.replace("http://www.yourdomain.com/procesar.php?var=usuario1")</script>
```

En el archivo procesar.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id_ad'] = $_GET['var'];
echo $_SESSION['id_ad'];
//output = usuario1
```

Por otra parte si no quieres que tus datos sean visibles cuando los envias podrías enviarlos por POST mediante ajax
En el javascript:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'procesar.php',
method : 'post',
data: {'var' : arguments[0]},
success: function (){
  alert("datos enviados");
}
});
```

En el archivo procesar.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id_ad'] = $_POST['var'];
echo $_SESSION['id_ad'];
//output = usuario1
```

Todo esto tomando en cuenta que el valor de arguments[0] es usuario1